# c3 (v4) scatter plot with two sets of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, scatter-plot, c3.js

I have the following csv file to plot two different sets of data: normal and global with its respective regression.

```
Access grade global,Grade_global,Regression_global,Access grade,Grade,Regression
11.48,6.0,5.66,11.48,6.0,5.74
11.43,5.6,5.63,11.43,5.6,5.69
12.13,5.9,6.16,12.13,5.9,6.55
10.48,5.0,4.91,10.48,5.0,4.52
10.54,4.7,4.96,10.54,4.7,4.6
10.23,5.1,4.73,10.23,5.1,4.22
12.27,5.5,6.26,12.27,5.5,6.71
11.13,4.2,5.4,11.13,4.2,5.32
13.7,10.0,7.34,13.7,10.0,8.46
```

I want to create a scatter plot with all the dots, each group in a different color and with its respective linear regressions (dots of the regression already calculated). I am trying to assign "Access grade global" and "Access grade" as x values to both the "Grade"/"Grade_global" and "Regression"/"Regression_global"

How can I do it? My actual code is:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart0',
    data: {
        url: '../static/CSV/Chart_data/grades_access_hs.csv?rnd='+(new Date).getTime(),
        xs: {
            Grade_global: 'Access grade global',
            Grade: 'Access grade'
        },
        type: 'scatter',
        types: {
            Regression_global: "line",
            Regression: 'line'
        },
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
        label: {
            text: "Average grade",
            position: "outer-middle"
        },
        min: 1,
        max: 9
        },
        x: {
        label: {
            text: "Access grade PAU",
            position: "outer-center"
        },
        min: 9,
        max: 14
        }
    },
    size: {
        height: 400,
        width: 800
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'inset',
        inset: {
        anchor: 'top-right',
        x: 20,
        y: 300,
        step: 1
        }
    },
})
```

I get the error: Uncaught Error: x is not defined for for id = "Regression_global".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your `x` in the wrong way. Referring to this [example](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_scatter.html), the chart constructor uses `xs`.

In your chart, defining the `xs` like this:

```
....
data: {
    url: '../static/CSV/Chart_data/grades_access_hs.csv?rnd='+(new Date).getTime(),
    xs: {
        'Access grade global': 'Access grade',
        'Calculus I global': 'Calculus I',
    },
    type: 'scatter'
},
....
```

should work.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ej0wXoRW8IAYQ2Ium32e?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks but this is still not working for me... I get the same error

Comment: @MTT Check out the plunker above.

Comment: @MTT So will there be 4 lines in total?

Comment: no, two sets of points in different colors (each with different vectors x and y) and two regressions (two lines, one for each x vector from the points)

Comment: @MTT Check the plunker now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171093/discussion-between-mtt-and-aditya-k).